# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lanenet_model' - Google Colab

Tags: python, python-import, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/MaybeShewill-CV/lanenet-lane-detection) repository for a lanenet implementation in google colab. After cloning the repository I'm want to test out the model by calling:

```
!python ./tools/test_lanenet.py --weights_path tusimple_lanenet.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001 --image_path test_img.jpg
```

I'm calling the file "test_lanenet.py" in the "tools" subfolder. This file tries to import another python file, which is in another subfolder (lanenet_model/lanenet.py) with:

```
from lanenet_model import lanenet
```

But then I get the Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/test_lanenet.py", line 20, in <module>
    from lanenet_model import lanenet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lanenet_model'
```

- every subfolder has an `__init__.py` file
- I already tried to add the subfolders to the pythonpath - didn't work
- When I print the Pythonpath, regardless of whether I print it in the colab command line or in the .py file, I see that I'm in the right folder (/content/lanenet-lane-detection)

Does anybody has an idea what I can do to fix the problem?

Here's the folder tree:
[lanenet folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccc2r.png)

Comment: In your screenshot `__init__.py` is missing in `tools` folder. Maybe try adding it there if you haven't already.

Comment: Also, you can try creating `__init__.py` in `lanenet-lane-detection` and try using `lanenet-lane-detection` as the main package. So: `from lanenet-lane-detection.lanenet_model import lanenet`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried both suggestions and both didn't work, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the .py file you want to run to the project root path, then run.
such as